# Changing the text value of a textview dynamically

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview in my XML layout file, but when I try to change its text value with code programatically (dynamically, depending on which button the user clicks) then the text of the textview doesn't change.

This is the code that I tried:

```
TextView userText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.User);

userText.setText(bundle.getString("user"));
```

In debug mode, I can see that `usertext` has the changed text, but the change doesn't appear on my mobile window... I don't know why.

EDIT: SOLVED!!!! it was a problem with my relative layout, text is out of the window!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
userText.invalidate()
```

Comment: it doesn't works....,    doing a debug mode, i can see that usertext haves the text changed, but doesn't appear on my movile window... i dont know why